# Logging within a ServerHandler

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't get my logging to work within my handler. Any ideas?

```
function doGet() {
  //...
  var box = app.getElementById('box').addItem('<Select>');
  for(var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    iamBox.addItem(members[i]);
  }

  var handler = app.createServerHandler("boxHandler");
  handler.addCallbackElement(box);
  box.addChangeHandler(handler);

  Logger.log('works');

  return app;
}

var handler = function(eventInfo)  {
  Logger.log('doesnt work');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1502) since june this year... I pray every day (;-) hoping they'll fix it.
In the meantime there is a very nice workaround by @megabyte1024 that is referenced on the issue tracker as well ([issue 1502, see last comment](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1502))

Comment: Thanks. I am using my own TextBoxDebug which I fill.